# Controller not registering when using nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app was working fine until I changed routing from ngRoute to ui-Router so I could use power of views within views. Now the controllers of the views are not being registered. My folder structure is like this:

[image]

**index.html**

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
  
      <div ui-view></div>

      <script src="js/app.module.js"></script>
      <script src="js/components/foodCategories/foodCategoriesController.js"></script>
      <!-- other controllers -->
      <script src="js/app.route.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.module.js**

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
```

**app.route.js**

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', statesManager])

function statesManager($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

  $stateProvider
    .state('profile', {
      url: '/profile',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: '/js/components/profile.html'
        },
        'foodCategories@profile': {
          templateUrl: '/js/components/foodCategories/foodCategories.html',
          controller: 'FoodCategoriesController'
        }
      }
    })
}
```

**profile.html**

```html
<div ui-view="foodCategories"></div>
```

**foodCategories.html**

```html
<div id="foodcategories" ng-controller="FoodCategoriesController">
<!-- other stuffs -->
```

**foodCategoriesController.js**

```js
(function () {
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('FoodCategoriesController', controlFunc)

  function controlFunc ($scope) {
  ....my stuffs...
  }
})()
```

I am not sure why the controller is not being registered. The controller file is loaded when I check Networks in Developers Tools but I get Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] on all controllers.
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `ng-controller="FoodCategoriesController"`. Remove it.

Comment: you're right!! i had already defined my controller for the template in app.route.js file. silly mistake . thank you :D

Comment: Welcome. :) Please mark as answer if it solved your issue